# How to restore Ubuntu to a previous version?

Tags: 16.10, restore

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 and I'm having some problems that I didn't have before, so I would want to know if it's possible to restore Ubuntu into 16.10 without losing files and apps.

Comment: What kinds of problems? Ask questions about them, they are probably solvable

Comment: I agree with @ cat. Why not try and solve your problems with 17.04?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, you should backup all your files and go for a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. If you're looking for a stable system, don't try the .10 or any non LTS versions unless you're using new hardware (that was just released). Unfortunately, Ubuntu doesn't do downgrades.

If your hard disk is large, I suggest you create a separate smaller partition where you will place a backup of all your files, and then install Ubuntu in the remaining portion of it. This makes data transfer much faster than using external media.

Comment: Normally reading and writing from the same media is slower than USB3 or similar.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Well, the partition would still be useful if the OP doesn't have a large capacity device to fit everything.

Comment: @Tim &  @ DouglasH.Silva
This is interesting. Any support for (Normally reading and writing from the same media is slower than USB3 or similar.) or some sort of reference. 
It's just too broad of a topic.

Comment: @Joraid most large drives are still disk drives. If you’re copying it to the same drive then the r/w head has to be in two places at once.

Comment: I always imaged R/W same disk will be faster from another media using USB. Okey, how any idea about SSD?

Comment: @Joraid I tried to replicate that with my drives, but I think I’m bottlenecking on the read from my internal hard drive. I did see a 20 MB/s difference on disk -> disk vs disk -> external, but the external -> disk was being funky.